Syntax nuances associated with converting old code
There are many errors, but they are mainly related to the part of the code where FORMAT is written. In this part, I separated some of the words “_”, since they were highlighted in color, which means the compiler perceived them not as explanations, but as a call to some action, I also replaced “=" with “equals”, removed the dots, so how the compiler cursed at them. If anyone has the opportunity, please help me correct the errors. I believe they are the same type. I use the 2012 code compiler in Code::Blocks so that it doesn't complain about "GO TO".
Source code link: https://acrobat.adobe.com/id/urn:aaid:sc:VA6C2:e77e5821-8991-4144-9711-d2ffcf868c0a
List of errors:
     |296|  296 .130:|||Error: Unexpected element 'Q' in format string  |
     |297|  297 .50:|||Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string  |
     |298|  298 .73:|||Error: Positive width required in format specifier E  |
     |299|  299 .39:|||Error: Unexpected element 'Y' in format string  |
     |300|  300 .75:|||Error: Positive width required in format specifier E  |
     |301|  301 .38:|||Error: Unexpected element 'U' in format string  |
     |302|  302 .95:|||Error: Unexpected element 'Q' in format string  |
     |303|  303 .132:|||Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string  |
     |306|  306 .171:|||Error: Positive width required in format specifier E  |
     |308|  308 .132:|||Error: Unexpected end of format string in format string  |
     |353|  353 .6:|||Error: Unclassifiable statement  |
     |15|  15 .16:|||Error: FORMAT label 6  not defined|
     |17|  17 .16:|||Error: FORMAT label 7  not defined|
     |19|  19 .16:|||Error: FORMAT label 8  not defined|
     |21|  21 .16:|||Error: FORMAT label 9  not defined|
     |23|  23 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 10  not defined|
     |26|  26 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 11  not defined|
     |27|  27 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 12  not defined|
     |58|  58 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 13  not defined|
     |351|  351 .14:|||Error: Label 20 referenced  is never defined|
     |157|  157 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 16  not defined|
     |221|  221 .17:|||Error: FORMAT label 18  not defined|
    ||=== Build finished: 24 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Code with numbered lines:
1         PROGRAM TWOFS
2   
3         COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
4         COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
5         COMMON/S3/C(100,100),B(100),P(100)
6   !
7         DIMENSION XM(50),YM(50),A(50),COSBET(50),SINBET(50),KOD(50)
8         DIMENSION TITLE(20)
9   !
10        READ (5,1) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
11        WRITE (6,2) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
12        READ (5,3) NUMBS,NUMOS,KSYM
13        READ (5,4) PR,E,XSYM,YSYM
14        READ (5,5) PXX,PYY,PXY
15        WRITE (6,6) NUMBS,NUMOS
16        GO TO (80,85,90,95), KSYM
17  80    WRITE (6,7)
18        GO TO 100
19  85    WRITE (6,8) XSYM
20        GO TO 100
21  90    WRITE (6,9) YSYM
22        GO TO 100
23  95    WRITE (6,10) XSYM,YSYM
24  !
25  100   CONTINUE
26        WRITE (6,11) PR,E
27        WRITE (6,12) PXX,PYY,PXY
28  !
29        PI=4.*ATAN(1.)
30        CON=1./(4.*PI*(1.-PR))
31        COND=(1.+PR)/E
32        PR1=1.-2.*PR
33        PR2=2.*(1.-PR)
34        PR3=3.-4.*PR
35  !
36  !   DEFINE LOCATIONS,SIZES,ORIENTATIONS AND BOUNDARY CONDITIONS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS
37  !
38        NUMBE=0
39        DO 110 N=1,NUMBS
40        READ (5,14) NUM,XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,KODE,BVS,BVN
41        XD=(XEND-XBEG)/NUM
42        YD=(YEND-YBEG)/NUM
43        SW=SQRT(XD*XD+YD*YD)
44  !
45        DO 110 NE=1,NUM
46        NUMBE=NUMBE+1
47        M=NUMBE
48        XM(M)=XBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*XD
49        YM(M)=YBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*YD
50        A(M)=0.5*SW
51        SINBET(M)=YD/SW
52        COSBET(M)=XD/SW
53        KOD(M)=KODE
54        MN=2*M
55        MS=MN-1
56        B(MS)=BVS
57  110   B(MN)=BVN
58        WRITE (6,13)
59        DO 115 M=1,NUMBE
60        SIZE=2.*A(M)
61        ANGLE=180.*ATAN2(SINBET(M),COSBET(M))/PI
62        WRITE (6,15) M,KOD(M),XM(M),YM(M),SIZE,ANGLE,B(2*M-1),B(2*M)
63  115   CONTINUE
64  !
65  !   ADJUST STRESS BOUNDARY VALUES TO ACCOUNT FOR INITIAL STRESSES.
66  !
67        DO 150 N=1,NUMBE
68        NN=2*N
69        NS=NN-1
70        COSB=COSBET(N)
71        SINB=SINBET(N)
72        SIGS=(PYY-PXX)*SINB*COSB+PXY*(COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB)
73        SIGN=PXX*SINB*SINB-2.*PXY*SINB*COSB+PYY*COSB*COSB
74        GO TO (120,150,130,140),KOD(N)
75  120   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
76        B(NN)=B(NN)-SIGN
77        GO TO 150
78  130   B(NN)=B(NN)-SIGN
79        GO TO 150
80  140   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
81  150   CONTINUE
82  !
83  !   COMPUTE INFLUENCE COEFFICIENTS AND SET UP SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
84  !
85        DO 300 I=1,NUMBE
86        IN=2*I
87        IS=IN-1
88        XI=XM(I)
89        YI=YM(I)
90        COSBI=COSBET(I)
91        SINBI=SINBET(I)
92        KODE=KOD(I)
93  !
94        DO 300 J=1,NUMBE
95        JN=2*J
96        JS=JN-1
97        CALL INITL
98        XJ=XM(J)
99        YJ=YM(J)
100       COSBJ=COSBET(J)
101       SINBJ=SINBET(J)
102       AJ=A(J)
103       CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
104       GO TO (240,210,220,230),KSYM
105 !
106 210   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
107       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
108       GO TO 240
109 !
110 220   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
111       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
112       GO TO 240
113 !
114 230   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
115       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
116       XJ=XM(J)
117       YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
118       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
119       XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
120       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
121 !
122 240   CONTINUE
123       GO TO (250,260,270,280),KODE
124 !
125 250   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
126       C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
127       C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
128       C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
129       GO TO 300
130 !
131 260   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
132       C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
133       C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
134       C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
135       GO TO 300
136 !
137 270   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
138       C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
139       C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
140       C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
141       GO TO 300
142 !
143 280   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
144       C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
145       C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
146       C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
147 !
148 300   CONTINUE
149 !
150 !   SOLVE SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
151 !
152       N=2*NUMBE
153       CALL SOLVE(N)
154 !
155 !   COMPUTE BOUNDARY DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES.
156 !
157       WRITE (6,16)
158       DO 600 I=1,NUMBE
159       XI=XM(I)
160       YI=YM(I)
161       COSBI=COSBET(I)
162       SINBI=SINBET(I)
163 !
164       UX=0.
165       UY=0.
166       SIGXX=PXX
167       SIGYY=PYY
168       SIGXY=PXY
169 !
170       DO 570 J=1,NUMBE
171       JN=2*J
172       JS=JN-1
173       CALL INITL
174       XJ=XM(J)
175       YJ=YM(J)
176       AJ=A(J)
177       COSBJ=COSBET(J)
178       SINBJ=SINBET(J)
179       CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
180       GO TO (540,510,520,530),KSYM
181 !
182 510   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
183       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
184       GO TO 540
185 !
186 520   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
187       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
188       GO TO 540
189 !
190 530   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
191       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
192       XJ=XM(J)
193       YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
194       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
195       XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
196       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
197 !
198 540   CONTINUE
199 !
200       UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
201       UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
202       SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
203       SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
204       SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
205 !
206 570   CONTINUE
207 !
208       US=UX*COSBI+UY*SINBI
209       UN=-UX*SINBI+UY*COSBI
210       SIGS=(SIGYY-SIGXX)*SINBI*COSBI+SIGXY*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
211       SIGN=SIGXX*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SIGXY*SINBI*COSBI+SIGYY*COSBI*COSBI
212       SIGT=SIGXX*COSBI*COSBI-2.*SIGXY*COSBI*SINBI+SIGYY*SINBI*SINBI
213 !
214       WRITE (6,17) I,UX,UY,US,UN,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY,SIGS,SIGN,SIGT
215 !
216 600   CONTINUE
217 !
218 !   COMPUTE DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS IN BOD
219 !
220       IF (NUMOS.LE.0) GO TO 900
221       WRITE (6,18)
222       NPOINT=0
223       DO 890 N=1,NUMOS
224       READ (5,19) XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,NUMPB
225       NUMP=NUMPB+1
226       DELX=(XEND-XBEG)/NUMP
227       DELY=(YEND-YBEG)/NUMP
228       IF (NUMPB.GT.0) NUMP=NUMP+1
229       IF (DELX**2+DELY**2.EQ.0.) NUMP=1
230 !
231       DO 890 NI=1,NUMP
232       XP=XBEG+(NI-1)*DELX
233       YP=YBEG+(NI-1)*DELY
234 !
235       UX=0.
236       UY=0.
237       SIGXX=PXX
238       SIGYY=PYY
239       SIGXY=PXY
240 !
241       DO 880 J=1,NUMBE
242       JN=2*J
243       JS=JN-1
244       CALL INITL
245       XJ=XM(J)
246       YJ=YM(J)
247       AJ=A(J)
248 !
249       IF (SQRT((XP-XJ)**2+(YP-YJ)**2).LT.2.*AJ) GO TO 890
250 !
251       COSBJ=COSBET(J)
252       SINBJ=SINBET(J)
253       CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
254       GO TO (840,810,820,830),KSYM
255 !
256 810   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
257       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
258       GO TO 840
259 !
260 820   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
261       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
262       GO TO 840
263 !
264 830   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
265       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
266       XJ=XM(J)
267       YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
268       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
269       XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
270       CALL KOEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
271 !
272 840   CONTINUE
273 !
274       UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
275       UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
276       SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
277       SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
278       SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
279 !
280 880   CONTINUE
281 !
282       NPOINT=NPOINT+1
283       WRITE (6,20) NPOINT,XP,YP,UX,UY,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY
284 !
285 890   CONTINUE
286 !
287 900   CONTINUE
288 !
289 !   FORMAT STATEMENTS.
290 !
291 1     FORMAT (20A4)
292 2     FORMAT (1H1,/,25X,20A4,/)
293 3     FORMAT (3I4)
294 4     FORMAT (F6.2,E11.4,2F12.4)
295 5     FORMAT (3E11.4)
296 6     FORMAT (/,109H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING AT LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED T_O DEFINE BOUNDARIES equals,I3,//,12 23H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED T_O SPECIFY OTHER LOCATIONS (I E, NO_T ON A BOUNDARY) WHER_E RESULTS ARE T_O BE FOUND =,I3)
297 7     FORMAT (/,32H NOSYMMETRY CONDITIONS IMPOSED)
298 8     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE X equals XS equals, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
299 9     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE Y equals YS equals, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
300 10    FORMAT (/,19H THE LINES X equals XS equals,F12.4,13H AND Y equals YS equals, F12.4,23H ARE LINES OF SYMMETRY)
301 11    FORMAT (/,18H POISSONS RATIO equals,F6.2,//,18H YOUNGS MODULUS equals,E11.14)
302 12    FORMAT (/,31H XX-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS -,E11.4,//,31H YY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS equals,E11.4,//,31H XY COMPONENTOF FIELD STRESS equals,E11.4)
303 13    FORMAT (1H1,/,27H BOUNDARY ELEMENT DAT_A,//,96H ELEMENT KODE X (CENTER) Y (CENTER) LENGTH ANGLE US OR SIGMA-S UN OR SIGMA-N,/)
304 14    FORMAT (I4,4F12.4,I4,2E11.4)
305 15    FORMAT (2I9,3F12.4,F12.2,2E15.4)
306 16    FORMAT (1H1,/,66H DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESS AT MIDPOINTS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS,//,40H ELEMENT UX UY US,60H UN SIGXX SIGYY SIGXY SIGMA-S SIGMA-N,10H SIGMA-T,/)
307 17    FORMAT (I10,4F10.6,6F10.1)
308 18    FORMAT (1H1,/,64H DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS I_N THE BODY,//,93H POINT X CO-ORD Y CO-ORD UX UY SIGXX SIGYY SIGXY,/)
309 19    FORMAT (4F12.4,I4)
310 20    FORMAT (I9,2F12.4,2F12.6,3F12.1)
311 !
312       END
313 
314       SUBROUTINE INITL
315 !
316       COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
317 !
318       SXXS=0.
319       SXXN=0.
320       SYYS=0.
321       SYYN=0.
322       SXYS=0.
323       SXYN=0.
324 !
325       UXS=0.
326       UXN=0.
327       UYS=0.
328       UYN=0.
329 !
330       RETURN
331       END
332 
333       SUBROUTINE COEFF(X,Y,CX,CY,A,COSB,SINB,MSYM)
334 !
335       COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
336       COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
337 !
338       COS2B=COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB
339       SIN2B=2.*SINB*COSB
340       XB=(X-CX)*COSB+(Y-CY)*SINB
341       YB=-(X-CX)*SINB+(Y-CY)*COSB
342 !
343       R1S=(XB-A)*(XB-A)+YB*YB
344       R2S=(XB+A)*(XB+A)+YB*YB
345       FL1=0.5*ALOG(R1S)
346       FL2=0.5*ALOG(R2S)
347       FB2=CON*(FL1-FL2)
348       IF (YB.NE.0.) GO TO 10
349       FB3=0.
350       IF (ABS(XB).LT.A) FB3=CON*PI
351       GO TO 20
352 10    FB3=-CON*(ATAN((XB+A)/YB)-ATAN((XB-A)/YB))
353 20    FB1=YB*FB3+CON*(XB-A)*FL1-(XB+A)*FL2)
354       FB4=CON*(YB/R1S-YB/R2S)
355       FB5=CON*((XB-A)/R1S-(XB+A)/R2S)
356 !
357       UXPS=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1+YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
358       UXPN=COND*(-PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
359       UYPS=COND*(PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
360       UYPN=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1-YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
361 !
362       SXXPS=FB2+PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)+YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
363       SXXPN=FB3-PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
364       SYYPS=FB2-PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
365       SYYPN=FB3+PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)-YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
366       SXYPS=PR2*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
367       SXYPN=PR1*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
368 !
369       UXS=UXS+MSYM*UXPS
370       UXN=UXN+UXPN
371       UYS=UYS+MSYM*UYPS
372       UYN=UYN+UYPN
373 !
374       SXXS=SXXS+MSYM*SXXPS
375       SXXN=SYYN+SXXPN
376       SYYS=SYYS+MSYM*SYYPS
377       SYYN=SYYN+SYYPN
378       SXYS=SXYS+MSYM*SXYPS
379       SXYN=SXYN+SXYPN
380 !
381       RETURN
382       END
383       SUBROUTINE SOLVE(N)
384 !
385       COMMON/S3/A(100,100),B(100),X(100)
386 !
387       NB=N-1
388       DO 20 J=1,NB
389       L=J+1
390       DO 20 JJ=L,N
391       XM=A(JJ,J)/A(J,J)
392       DO 10 I=J,N
393 10    A(JJ,I)=A(JJ,I)-A(J,I)*XM
394 20    B(JJ)=B(JJ)-B(J)*XM
395 !
396       X(N)=B(N)/A(N,N)
397       DO 40 J=1,NB
398       JJ=N-J
399       L=JJ+1
400       SUM=0.
401       DO 30 I=L,N
402 30    SUM=SUM+A(JJ,I)*X(I)
403 40    X(JJ)=(B(JJ)-SUM)/(A(JJ,JJ))
404 !
405       RETURN
406       END

Updated code:
      PROGRAM TWOFS
!
      COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
      COMMON/S3/C(100,100),B(100),P(100)
!
      DIMENSION XM(50),YM(50),A(50),COSBET(50),SINBET(50),KOD(50)
      DIMENSION TITLE(20)
!
      READ (5,1) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
      WRITE (6,2) (TITLE(I),I=1,20)
      READ (5,3) NUMBS,NUMOS,KSYM
      READ (5,4) PR,E,XSYM,YSYM
      READ (5,5) PXX,PYY,PXY
      WRITE (6,6) NUMBS,NUMOS
      GO TO (80,85,90,95), KSYM
80    WRITE (6,7)
      GO TO 100
85    WRITE (6,8) XSYM
      GO TO 100
90    WRITE (6,9) YSYM
      GO TO 100
95    WRITE (6,10) XSYM,YSYM
!
100   CONTINUE
      WRITE (6,11) PR,E
      WRITE (6,12) PXX,PYY,PXY
!
      PI=4.*ATAN(1.)
      CON=1./(4.*PI*(1.-PR))
      COND=(1.+PR)/E
      PR1=1.-2.*PR
      PR2=2.*(1.-PR)
      PR3=3.-4.*PR
!
!   DEFINE LOCATIONS,SIZES,ORIENTATIONS AND BOUNDARY CONDITIONS OF BOUNDARY ELEMENTS
!
      NUMBE=0
      DO 110 N=1,NUMBS
      READ (5,14) NUM,XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,KODE,BVS,BVN
      XD=(XEND-XBEG)/NUM
      YD=(YEND-YBEG)/NUM
      SW=SQRT(XD*XD+YD*YD)
!
      DO 110 NE=1,NUM
      NUMBE=NUMBE+1
      M=NUMBE
      XM(M)=XBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*XD
      YM(M)=YBEG+0.5*(2.*NE-1.)*YD
      A(M)=0.5*SW
      SINBET(M)=YD/SW
      COSBET(M)=XD/SW
      KOD(M)=KODE
      MN=2*M
      MS=MN-1
      B(MS)=BVS
110   B(MN)=BVN
      WRITE (6,13)
      DO 115 M=1,NUMBE
      SIZE=2.*A(M)
      ANGLE=180.*ATAN2(SINBET(M),COSBET(M))/PI
      WRITE (6,15) M,KOD(M),XM(M),YM(M),SIZE,ANGLE,B(2*M-1),B(2*M)
115   CONTINUE
!
!   ADJUST STRESS BOUNDARY VALUES TO ACCOUNT FOR INITIAL STRESSES.
!
      DO 150 N=1,NUMBE
      NN=2*N
      NS=NN-1
      COSB=COSBET(N)
      SINB=SINBET(N)
      SIGS=(PYY-PXX)*SINB*COSB+PXY*(COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB)
      SIG_N=PXX*SINB*SINB-2.*PXY*SINB*COSB+PYY*COSB*COSB
      GO TO (120,150,130,140),KOD(N)
120   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
      B(NN)=B(NN)-SIG_N
      GO TO 150
130   B(NN)=B(NN)-SIG_N
      GO TO 150
140   B(NS)=B(NS)-SIGS
150   CONTINUE
!
!   COMPUTE INFLUENCE COEFFICIENTS AND SET UP SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
!
      DO 300 I=1,NUMBE
      IN=2*I
      IS=IN-1
      XI=XM(I)
      YI=YM(I)
      COSBI=COSBET(I)
      SINBI=SINBET(I)
      KODE=KOD(I)
!
      DO 300 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      AJ=A(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (240,210,220,230),KSYM
!
210   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 240
!
220   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 240
!
230   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
240   CONTINUE
      GO TO (250,260,270,280),KODE
!
250   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
260   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
      C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
      C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
270   C(IS,JS)=UXS*COSBI+UYS*SINBI
      C(IS,JN)=UXN*COSBI+UYN*SINBI
      C(IN,JS)=SXXS*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYS*SINBI*COSBI+SYYS*COSBI*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=SXXN*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SXYN*SINBI*COSBI+SYYN*COSBI*COSBI
      GO TO 300
!
280   C(IS,JS)=(SYYS-SXXS)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYS*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IS,JN)=(SYYN-SXXN)*SINBI*COSBI+SXYN*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      C(IN,JS)=-UXS*SINBI+UYS*COSBI
      C(IN,JN)=-UXN*SINBI+UYN*COSBI
!
300   CONTINUE
!
!   SOLVE SYSTEM OF ALGEBRAIC EQUATIONS.
!
      N=2*NUMBE
      CALL SOLVE(N)
!
!   COMPUTE BOUNDARY DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES.
!
      WRITE (6,16)
      DO 600 I=1,NUMBE
      XI=XM(I)
      YI=YM(I)
      COSBI=COSBET(I)
      SINBI=SINBET(I)
!
      UX=0.
      UY=0.
      SIGXX=PXX
      SIGYY=PYY
      SIGXY=PXY
!
      DO 570 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      AJ=A(J)
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (540,510,520,530),KSYM
!
510   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 540
!
520   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 540
!
530   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XI,YI,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
540   CONTINUE
!
      UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
      UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
      SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
      SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
      SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
!
570   CONTINUE
!
      US=UX*COSBI+UY*SINBI
      UN=-UX*SINBI+UY*COSBI
      SIGS=(SIGYY-SIGXX)*SINBI*COSBI+SIGXY*(COSBI*COSBI-SINBI*SINBI)
      SIG_N=SIGXX*SINBI*SINBI-2.*SIGXY*SINBI*COSBI+SIGYY*COSBI*COSBI
      SIGT=SIGXX*COSBI*COSBI+2.*SIGXY*COSBI*SINBI+SIGYY*SINBI*SINBI
!
      WRITE (6,17) I,UX,UY,US,UN,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY,SIGS,SIG_N,SIGT
!
600   CONTINUE
!
!   COMPUTE DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POINTS IN BOD
!
      IF (NUMOS.LE.0) GO TO 900
      WRITE (6,18)
      NPOINT=0
      DO 890 N=1,NUMOS
      READ (5,19) XBEG,YBEG,XEND,YEND,NUMPB
      NUMP=NUMPB+1
      DELX=(XEND-XBEG)/NUMP
      DELY=(YEND-YBEG)/NUMP
      IF (NUMPB.GT.0) NUMP=NUMP+1
      IF (DELX**2+DELY**2.EQ.0.) NUMP=1
!
      DO 890 NI=1,NUMP
      XP=XBEG+(NI-1)*DELX
      YP=YBEG+(NI-1)*DELY
!
      UX=0.
      UY=0.
      SIGXX=PXX
      SIGYY=PYY
      SIGXY=PXY
!
      DO 880 J=1,NUMBE
      JN=2*J
      JS=JN-1
      CALL INITL
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=YM(J)
      AJ=A(J)
!
      IF (SQRT((XP-XJ)**2+(YP-YJ)**2).LT.2.*AJ) GO TO 890
!
      COSBJ=COSBET(J)
      SINBJ=SINBET(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,SINBJ,+1)
      GO TO (840,810,820,830),KSYM
!
810   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 840
!
820   YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      GO TO 840
!
830   XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,COSBJ,-SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=XM(J)
      YJ=2.*YSYM-YM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,SINBJ,-1)
      XJ=2.*XSYM-XM(J)
      CALL COEFF(XP,YP,XJ,YJ,AJ,-COSBJ,-SINBJ,+1)
!
840   CONTINUE
!
      UX=UX+UXS*P(JS)+UXN*P(JN)
      UY=UY+UYS*P(JS)+UYN*P(JN)
      SIGXX=SIGXX+SXXS*P(JS)+SXXN*P(JN)
      SIGYY=SIGYY+SYYS*P(JS)+SYYN*P(JN)
      SIGXY=SIGXY+SXYS*P(JS)+SXYN*P(JN)
!
880   CONTINUE
!
      NPOINT=NPOINT+1
      WRITE (6,20) NPOINT,XP,YP,UX,UY,SIGXX,SIGYY,SIGXY
!
890   CONTINUE
!
900   CONTINUE
!
!   FORMAT STATEMENTS.
!
1     FORMAT (20A4)
2     FORMAT (1H1,/,25X,20A4,/)
3     FORMAT (3I4)
4     FORMAT (F6.2,E11.4,2F12.4)
5     FORMAT (3E11.4)
6     FORMAT (/,109H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING A&
     T LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED T_O DEFINE BOUNDARIES =,I3,//,12&
     6H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED T_O SPECIFY OTHER LOCATION&
     S (IE, NO_T ON A BOUNDARY) WHER_E RESULTS ARE T_O BE FOUND =,I3)
7     FORMAT (/,31H NO SYMMETRY CONDITIONS IMPOSED)
8     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE X = XS =, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
9     FORMAT (/,18H THE LINE Y = YS =, F12.4,23H I_S A LINE OF SYMMETRY)
10    FORMAT (/,19H THE LINES X = XS =,F12.4,13H AND Y = YS =, F12.4,&
     22H ARE LINES OF SYMMETRY)
11    FORMAT (/,17H POISSONS RATIO =,F6.2,//,17H YOUNGS MODULUS =,E11.&
     4)
12    FORMAT (/,31H XX-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4,//,31H YY-COMPO&
     NENT OF FIELD STRESS =,E11.4,//,31H XY-COMPONENT OF FIELD STRESS =&
     ,E11.4)
13    FORMAT (1H1,/,27H     BOUNDARY ELEMENT DAT_A,//,96H  ELEMENT     K&
     ODE  X (CENTER)  Y (CENTER)      LENGTH       ANGLE  US OR SIGMA-S&
       UN OR SIGMA-N,/)
14    FORMAT (I4,4F12.4,I4,2E11.4)
15    FORMAT (2I9,3F12.4,F12.2,2E15.4)
16    FORMAT (1H1,/,65H     DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT MIDPOINTS OF B&
     OUNDARY ELEMENTS,//,40H   ELEMENT        UX        UY        US,&
      60H UN        SIGXX     SIGYY     SIGXY     SIGMA-S     SIGMA-N,&
      10H   SIGMA-T,/)
17    FORMAT (I10,4F10.6,6F10.1)
18    FORMAT (1H1,/,64H     DISPLACEMENTS AND STRESSES AT SPECIFIED POIN&
     TS I_N THE BODY,//,93H    POINT    X CO-ORD    Y CO-ORD          U&
     X          UY       SIGXX       SIGYY       SIGXY,/)
19    FORMAT (4F12.4,I4)
20    FORMAT (I9,2F12.4,2F12.6,3F12.1)
!
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE INITL
!
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
!
      SXXS=0.
      SXXN=0.
      SYYS=0.
      SYYN=0.
      SXYS=0.
      SXYN=0.
!
      UXS=0.
      UXN=0.
      UYS=0.
      UYN=0.
!
      RETURN
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE COEFF(X,Y,CX,CY,A,COSB,SINB,MSYM)
!
      COMMON/S1/PI,PR,PR1,PR2,PR3,CON,COND
      COMMON/S2/SXXS,SXXN,SYYS,SYYN,SXYS,SXYN,UXS,UXN,UYS,UYN
!
      COS2B=COSB*COSB-SINB*SINB
      SIN2B=2.*SINB*COSB
!
      XB=(X-CX)*COSB+(Y-CY)*SINB
      YB=-(X-CX)*SINB+(Y-CY)*COSB
!
      R1S=(XB-A)*(XB-A)+YB*YB
      R2S=(XB+A)*(XB+A)+YB*YB
      FL1=0.5*ALOG(R1S)
      FL2=0.5*ALOG(R2S)
      FB2=CON*(FL1-FL2)
      IF (YB.NE.0.) GO TO 10
      FB3=0.
      IF (ABS(XB).LT.A) FB3=CON*PI
      GO TO 20
10    FB3=-CON*(ATAN((XB+A)/YB)-ATAN((XB-A)/YB))
20    FB1=YB*FB3+CON*((XB-A)*FL1-(XB+A)*FL2)
      FB4=CON*(YB/R1S-YB/R2S)
      FB5=CON*((XB-A)/R1S-(XB+A)/R2S)
!
      UXPS=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1+YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
      UXPN=COND*(-PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
      UYPS=COND*(PR3*SINB*FB1-YB*(COSB*FB2-SINB*FB3))
      UYPN=COND*(PR3*COSB*FB1-YB*(SINB*FB2+COSB*FB3))
!
      SXXPS=FB2+PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)+YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
      SXXPN=FB3-PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SYYPS=FB2-PR2*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
      SYYPN=FB3+PR1*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)-YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SXYPS=PR2*(SIN2B*FB2+COS2B*FB3)+YB*(SIN2B*FB4-COS2B*FB5)
      SXYPN=PR1*(COS2B*FB2-SIN2B*FB3)-YB*(COS2B*FB4+SIN2B*FB5)
!
      UXS=UXS+MSYM*UXPS
      UXN=UXN+UXPN
      UYS=UYS+MSYM*UYPS
      UYN=UYN+UYPN
!
      SXXS=SXXS+MSYM*SXXPS
      SXXN=SXXN+SXXPN
      SYYS=SYYS+MSYM*SYYPS
      SYYN=SYYN+SYYPN
      SXYS=SXYS+MSYM*SXYPS
      SXYN=SXYN+SXYPN
!
      RETURN
      END
!
      SUBROUTINE SOLVE(N)
!
      COMMON/S3/A(100,100),B(100),X(100)
!
      NB=N-1
      DO 20 J=1,NB
      L=J+1
      DO 20 JJ=L,N
      XM=A(JJ,J)/A(J,J)
      DO 10 I=J,N
10    A(JJ,I)=A(JJ,I)-A(J,I)*XM
20    B(JJ)=B(JJ)-B(J)*XM
!
      X(N)=B(N)/A(N,N)
      DO 40 J=1,NB
      JJ=N-J
      L=JJ+1
      SUMM=0.
      DO 30 I=L,N
30    SUMM=SUMM+A(JJ,I)*X(I)
40    X(JJ)=(B(JJ)-SUMM)/A(JJ,JJ)
!
      RETURN
      END



Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Read the instructions displayed when adding a tag.

As you were told several times already you really must fix your indentation. Fixed/form Fortran source files have statements have statements starting at column 7, not column 5 and statement labels are in columns 1-4. If, instead, you are compiling your code as free-form source, your file must be named appropriately. Show the file name and the full command you use for compilation. When showing any compiler errors, always show the command that produced those errors.

Be aware that in standard Fortran the main program cannot have arguments like (INPUT,OUTPUT,TAPE5=INPUT,TAPE6=OUTPUT). You can create a question that will be specifically about this aspect . Most likely, you can just remove this bit and keep just PROGRAM TWOFS, because most compilers will pre-connect units 5 and 6 for you.

@Vladimir F Героям слава, I updated the indentation and the first line of code. The errors remain the same. I probably didn't fully understand you.

Show us the file name, the exact compilation command you use and the updated copy of the error messages. Foremost, it is completely necessary to know whether your file's extension is .f, .for, .f90 or something else.

@Vladimir F Героям слава, file name: test.f90.

Now it looks like much better. Most of the problems seem to just stem from the FORMAT statements. Some of the probably aren't even too important. Did you modify the messages to be printed in any way?

@Vladimir F Героям слава, I numbered the lines. Please tell me how to get rid of the remaining errors?

I ask again. Did you modify the messages to be printed in the FORMAT statements in any way?

D0 570 J=1,NUMBE should obviously have DO, not D0. I believe these issues were already pointed out under the previoues question.

@Vladimir F Героям слава, In this part, I separated some of the words “_”, since they were highlighted in color, which means the compiler perceived them not as explanations, but as a call to some action, I also replaced “=" with “equals”, removed the dots, so how the compiler cursed at them.
Errors related to the confusion of 0 and O have been fixed.

Do not change anything in the FORMAT statements unless you understand how the syntax works. See how the H descriptor is used in the documentation or.in some of the SO questions. The number before the H descriptor must match the number of the characters in the string. It is easier to just remove the H descriptor and put there a string directly. Again, see the documentation or other questions about how to do that. Someone may show you something in an answer here as well.

@Vladimir F Героям слава, I didn't touch the descriptors. I only changed the words (text). I deleted dots at the end of sentences, and used an underscore to separate words into parts if they were displayed in a color other than black, since, as I understood, this meant that the compiler perceived the words as operators and not text.

Take
 FORMAT (/,109H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS (EACH COUNTING AT LEAST ONE BOUNDARY ELEMENT) USED T_O DEFINE BOUNDARIES equals,I3,//,12 23H NUMBE_R OF STRAIGHT-LINE SEGMENTS USED T_O SPECIFY OTHER LOCATIONS (I E, NO_T ON A BOUNDARY) WHER_E RESULTS ARE T_O BE FOUND =,I3)

This format specification uses an ancient and now deleted feature of Fortran called Hollerith editing. Basically, after 109H there are exactly 109 characters to be printed.
For some not very good reason (apparently due to syntax highlighting of your code editor) you added multiple _ characters. That means that the text is now longer than those 109 characters so characters after character 109 are being interpreted as another part of a Fortran format specification or format string string. That cannot work.
Do not add characters into parts with Hollerith editing unless you adjust the number before the H descriptor accordingly. There are much better alternatives to Hollerith editing as brought by FORTRAN 77 and more recent versions of the standard. See, for example Fortran: FORMAT statement over two lines but certainly study some documentation about Fortran format syntax.

I took your answer into account and managed to reduce it to 10 errors, divided into two groups. Please tell me what needs to be fixed next? I added the latest results to the original question.

@Mark The rest means that you exceed the maximum line length for free-form Fortran until Fortran 2018. You can use a compiler option to increase the limit or split the statements into two lines. Follow the usual rules for line continuation. The repeated & character on the new line may be very handy. This Q/A is for strings but the rules are more general.

@Mark However, do not make edits that invalidates existing answers. You can add your new error messages and the new code as an update (although often it is better to open a new question), but do not just remove the parts that you fixed by an existing answer. I rolled back your edit.

Following your recommendations, I fixed the current errors, but a new group appeared:
program\test.o:test.f90|| undefined reference to `koeff_'|
...
program\test.o:test.f90|| undefined reference to `koeff_'|
program\test.o:test.f90|| more undefined references to `koeff_' follow|
||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
What should I do to fix them?
I tried moving the KOEFF function and others to the beginning, before "PROGRAM TWOFS", but it did not help.

@Mark You do not have any function KOEFF, only COEFF.

This is really a material for a new question.
